# The payload is invalid - Nothing has changed. Errors every minute

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I'm getting a DecryptException error on Laravel via automated error emails. I can see in the trace what's happening but I have no idea why, or how to fix this. I have logged out all users, cleared cache, even changed the app key and still nothing has changed. The site is functioning as it should, but these error emails are coming through every 30 seconds or so.

[image: Error Trace]

Comment: you are getting wrong dycription id.

Comment: Do you know how this might have happened, or how to solve it? Or even how to debug to see specifically where it's happening? @VikasKatariya

Comment: share your code of controller and blade file.

Comment: The full trace of the error uses no controllers, this is what I do not understand. It's not anything in my code. @VikasKatariya

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption#decrypting-a-value you might need to wrap some code in a try catch block?

Comment: Thank you @Aless55 - Where would this code go? The files with the errors are part of the Laravel core files. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: @ItsJoeTurner are you storing that encrypted value in db ? then can you show length of field and type.If you are fetching from db and then sending email then there might chance of partially saved token

Comment: I'm not, it's by file. I removed the session files already and cleared the cache, as well as removing the log in tokens from the DB for the users. Is it worth noting that every single error is showing the same token ('eyJpdiI6Imx3RmkxM...') as in the first example? @JohnLobo - Currently getting 3 error emails per minute. Seem to have exhausted all options. Users can still log in, save things. No visible issues on the site.